# Intuition behind density functions

Tags: probability-theory, approximation, density-function

The following intuitive example is sometimes given when density functions are introduced (see equation (1) [here](http://mathinsight.org/probability_density_function_idea), for example)

> Suppose that $X$ is a random variable with an absolutely continuous distribution and a density function $f$. Then
>   $$
> P(x<X\le x+\varepsilon)\approx f(x)\cdot\varepsilon
> $$
>   for small values of $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$.

I think I intuitively understand the idea behind this example, but is it possible to make this example rigorous? For instance, is it true that
$$
\frac{P(x<X\le x+\varepsilon)}{f(x)\cdot\varepsilon}\to1
$$
as $\varepsilon\to0$ provided that $f(x)>0$? Is it possible to establish a similar statement (maybe under additional assumptions)?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has actually little to do with probabilites.

If you take for granted that the random variable has a $\text{cdf}$, this means that

$$\mathbb P(X\le x)=\text{cdf}_X(x).$$ From there, by the mean value theorem,

$$\mathbb P(x<X\le x+\epsilon)=\text{cdf}_X(x+\epsilon)-\text{cdf}_X(x)= \epsilon\frac d{dx}\text{cdf}_X{(x+\mu\epsilon)}$$ if the $\text{cdf}$ is a differentiable function.

Also

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\text{cdf}_X(x+\epsilon)-\text{cdf}_X(x)}\epsilon=\frac d{dx}\text{cdf}_X{(x)}=:\text{pdf}_X(x),$$ which you called $f$.

Comment: Note that this works out at points where the CDF is actually differentiable. Sometimes we define a PDF at points where the corresponding CDF is actually not differentiable, and at these points the approximation given in the OP does not hold. The exponential distribution at $x=0$ gives an example.